# Number slider with different min max

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an app where user slides the **slider** to select a compass direction, but we all know that sliders usually starts at **0 (left)** and ends at **N (right)**.

I am trying to replicate this:
[image: compass image]

Bottomline, I want the slider to start at `270(West)` and the center should be `360` and `0(0 degree North)` and next should be `0-90(North to East)` then `90-180(East to South)` and then `180-269(South to West)`

Sorry for bad english, not native speaker. If my explanation is not understandable, please refer to the image.

Comment: Hey there, welcome to StackOverflow! Please share what you have tried. What problems are you facing?

Comment: it is an input type range. As explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) you can use value to make it start at a default value. The degrees there should be handled by javascript manipulating the default html

Comment: Seeing as you have 90 degrees on one side, and 270 on the other, it might be a bit tough to get the 'North' in the middle of the compass.

Comment: What do you have so far? Adding a `min`, `max` and initial `value` seems simple enough if you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) that's already been linked in the comments.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you start the slider on 270 degrees, then the center would be 90 degrees, because your compass is not centered on the slider range.
You can use negative values to determine the applicable direction with some math:

```js
$('#slider-degrees').change(() => {
  let selection = parseInt($('#slider-degrees').val());
  let degrees = (selection < 0) ? (360 + selection) : selection;
  $('#label-degrees').html(degrees);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="slider-degrees" type="range" min="-90" max="269" value="-90">
<span id="label-degrees"></span>
```